# how hide/show JRibbonBand of RibbonTask by a JCommandToggleButton of another RibbonTask in flamingo java

Tags: java, radiance-flamingo

I created two RibbonTask in my JRibbonFrame and each of them has some JRibbonBand, i want hide/show a specific JRibbonBand of RibbonTask by a JCommandToggleButton of another RibbonTask.

I use

```
this.getRibbon().getTask(0).getBand(1).setVisible()
```

but when i click on RibbonTask i see that RibbonTask again.